# Попробуй меня перевести или другие приключения SESSION?

Tags: php

Такой вопрос.
У меня есть страница, где указана ссылка на личную страницу, по которой ты проходишь, и она в штатном режиме генерирует твою личную страницу. Я задумался, а вдруг будет неавторизованный пользователь? И что тогда делать?

Я начал углубляться в вопрос, и пришёл к выводу, что неавторизованный пользователь должен отправляться авторизовываться, если он хочет в личный кабинет!

Но вот незадача. С таким кодом:

```
  if (isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"])) {
header('Location: office.php?id='. $_SESSION['id']);
} else {
  header ('Location: index.html');
}
```

Он авторизованных пользователей отправляет на их личную страницу, а не авторизованным пользователям, он генерирует их личную временную страницу без каких-либо данных.

Вопрос состоит в том, как мне отправить их на другую страницу, в данным случае, на главную.

На сколько я понял, проблема в этой строчке:

```
  if (isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"])) {
```

Но что я туда только не вписывал, результата не достигал. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону мне двигаться?

С уважением, Вячеслав.

Comment: Как вы вставляете значение в $_COOKIE

Comment: а вы проверяйте не куку, а наличие `$_SESSION['id']`, если есть переправляйте. но там в файле тоже проверяйте все равно.

Comment: @teran , расскажите пожалуйста по подробнее об этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё! Вопрос решён. Всем кто пытался мне помочь в этом вопросе, благодарность.

Суть решения заключается в этих строчках:

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
header('Location: office.php?id='. $_SESSION['id']);
}
  else {
    session_destroy();
    header ('Location: index.html');
  }
```

А генерировал ЛК судя по всему, из-за не разрушенной сессии, которая стартовала в начале документа.